# Division issues in C

Tags: c, math, division

I don't really know how to explain this (that's why the title was to vague) but I need a way to make C divide in a certain way, I need to make c divide without any decimals in the answer (besides the remainder) for example;

Instead of `5.21 / .25 = 20.84`
I need this  `5.21 / .25 = *20*  Remainder = *.21*`

I found out how to find the remainder with `Fmod()`  but how do I find the `20`?

Thanks ~

Comment: Store the result in an `int`, or use the floor function.

Comment: Example of where `int` fails `double x = pow(2,32), ip; modf(x, &ip); printf("%f %f %d\n", x, ip, (int) x);` --> `4294967296.000000 4294967296.000000 -2147483648`

Answer (score 2):

how about using implicit casts?

```
float  k = 5.21 / .25;
int n = k;
k -= n;
```

results in

```
k = .84
n = 20
```

using only ints will also do the job if you don't need the remainder

```
int k = 5.21 / .25
```

will automatically truncate k and get `k = 20`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm a beginner at coding in C so if I make any mistake please correct me, but in this situation I just discard `k` and than use fmod() to get the remainder right? and than I would have my remainder = .21 and `n = 20` If so thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2):

Use `double modf(double value, double *iptr)` to extract the integer portion of a FP number.

> The modf functions break the argument value into integral and fractional parts, each of which has the same type and sign as the argument.  C11 §7.12.6.12 2

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  double a = 5.21;
  double b = 0.25;
  double q = a / b;
  double r = fmod(a, b);
  printf("quotient: %f\n", q);
  printf("remander: %f\n", r);
  double ipart;
  double fpart = modf(q, &ipart);
  printf("quotient i part: %f\n", ipart);
  printf("quotient f part: %f\n", fpart);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
quotient: 20.840000
remander: 0.210000
quotient i part: 20.000000
quotient f part: 0.840000
```

Using `int` is problematic due to a limited range, precision and sign issues.

Comment: hmm, I didn't think of the problems with using int, thanks!

Comment: @MatthewH In _general_, good to minimize mixing types, especially between floating pointer and integer types in an equation.  Many pitfalls.

Comment: if I could bother you for one more minute, how do I find every number between two values? like 
`if (x = 1 through 10) `
what would I replace through with?

Comment: @MatthewH Unclear.  Does the result include the end values of 1 and 10?  As your post is about `double`, do you want _every_ `double` 1 to 10, including 1.5, 6.25, etc?  Perhaps pose your question with more detail as a new SO post.  What about `for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)`?

Comment: What I need is a away to check for every number between two values, after the values are checked for they are not used again.

If (x = a through b) than do this code. I do not need a `double` for every number between a through b, just away to check for them.

Comment: @MatthewH Is not `if (x >= a && a <= b) do_this_code();` good enough?